# Authenticating using Azure Active Directory with Angular 13 and .NET core web api

Tags: angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I have a .NET CORE 6 Api for the back end and a Angular 13 for the front end. Currently I am trying to authenticate via Angular using `msal` and then call the protected .net core API. I think I am missing something. The Api is the `weatherforcast` Api template. It successfully authenticates via **AAD**, which allows me to get user information. However when I try to request data via api by invoking the `http.get` method its not Authorizing. How does the protected API get authorization from the front end? Both Apps are registered in Azure Active directory. From my understanding the `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` should intercept the access token and authorization for the api should be granted. The `ProfileComponent` has `MsalGuard`.

app.module.ts

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Configuration } from 'msal';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { BrowserCacheLocation, InteractionType, IPublicClientApplication, LogLevel, PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { MsalGuard, MsalInterceptor, MsalBroadcastService, MsalInterceptorConfiguration, MsalModule, MsalService, MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG, MSAL_INSTANCE, MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG, MsalGuardConfiguration, MsalRedirectComponent } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field'
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox'
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input'
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button'
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider'




const isIE = window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > -1 || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/") > -1;

export function loggerCallback(logLevel: LogLevel, message: string) {
  console.log(message);
}

export function MSALInstanceFactory(): IPublicClientApplication {
  return new PublicClientApplication({
    auth: {
      clientId: environment.clientId,
      authority: environment.authority,
      redirectUri: environment.redirectUrl,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: environment.redirectUrl,
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: BrowserCacheLocation.LocalStorage,
      storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
    },
    system: {
      loggerOptions: {
        loggerCallback,
        logLevel: LogLevel.Info,
        piiLoggingEnabled: false
      }
    }
  });
}
export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
  const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();
  protectedResourceMap.set('api://{uri id}', ['name.read']);

  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    protectedResourceMap
  };
}

export function MSALGuardConfigFactory(): MsalGuardConfiguration {
  return { interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect };
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MsalModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatDividerModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
      useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory
    },
    MsalService,
    MsalGuard,
    MsalBroadcastService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

profile.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { ApiService } from '../services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  forecasts: any;
  name: any;
  username: any;



  constructor(private _apiService: ApiService, private _msalService: MsalService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    const account = this._msalService.instance.getAllAccounts()[0];
    this.name = account?.name;
    this.username = account?.username;

    this._apiService.getForcast().subscribe(result => {
      this.forecasts = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));
  }

}
```

appsettings.json

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "example.com",
    "TenantId": "{TenantId}",
    "ClientId": "{ClientId}",
    "Scopes": "name.write name.read",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Audience": "api://{uri id}"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check your protected resource map.  You currently have "api://{uri id}".  Try placing the actual API url here just to test it out.  Something similar to... "http://localhost:1448/api/weatherforecasts", or whatever the endpoint would be.  When you make the call, look to see if the authorization header is in the request.